# error 1005 errno105

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, innodb, foreign-key-relationship

I have searched for the problem but cant find a solution.

Its a one-to-one relation and i have the same problem with an other table that has a FK to staff

i keep getting a

```
  error 1005 error no 105
```

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `staff` (
  `StaffNumber` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `Firstname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Lastname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Insertion` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StaffNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `airmarshall` (
  `weaponNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Nationality` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Snumber` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `SnumberA` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Snumber`,`SnumberA`),
  CONSTRAINT `staff_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Snumber`) REFERENCES `staff` (`StaffNumber`)     
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: In which you are getting the errors? Add some relevant information

Comment: i get it when i add airmarshall because the error i keep getting is only when i add the FK.

Comment: Can u please set default storage as InnoDB in my.cnf ?

Comment: oke that works... Weird but thanks!

Comment: fine .. Did you make any changes?

Comment: only i the my.cnf file i uncommented the part that says skip innoDB and than i restarted MySQL workbench and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 In Mysql Server version: 5.1.60   


mysql> CREATE TABLE `staff` (   `StaffNumber` varchar(5) NOT NULL,   `Firstname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,   `Lastname` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,   `Insertion` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`StaffNumber`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec)


    mysql> CREATE TABLE `airmarshall` (
        ->   `weaponNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
        ->   `Nationality` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        ->   `Snumber` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
        ->   `SnumberA` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
        ->   PRIMARY KEY (`Snumber`,`SnumberA`),
        ->   CONSTRAINT `staff_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Snumber`) REFERENCES `staff` (`StaffNumber`)     
        ->   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ->  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)

    mysql> show create table airmarshall;
    -----------------------------------+
    | airmarshall | CREATE TABLE `airmarshall` (
      `weaponNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `Nationality` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `Snumber` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
      `SnumberA` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`Snumber`,`SnumberA`),
      CONSTRAINT `staff_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Snumber`) REFERENCES `staff` (`StaffNumber`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```